glMultiDrawArraysIndirect is not drawing anything
This code works:
unsigned int n;
for (n = 0; n < draw_count; n++) {
     const DrawArraysIndirectCommand *cmd;
     cmd = (const DrawArraysIndirectCommand  *)draw_data + n;
     set_uniform_int("draw_call", n, program);
     glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, cmd->first, cmd->count, cmd->instanceCount, cmd->baseInstance);
}

Replacing this with glMultiDrawArraysIndirect doesn't render anything:
glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, (GLvoid*)0, draw_count, 0);

Before I do this, I bind:
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, vb->m_draw_call_ib);
glBufferSubData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, 0, draw_count * sizeof(DrawArraysIndirectCommand), draw_data);
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, 0);

glBindVertexArray(vb->m_vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, vb->m_draw_call_ib);

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 5, vb->m_chunk_ssbo);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 4, vb->m_draw_ssbo);

Do I need a specific version of opengl, why would this not work on the khronos page they said that glMultiDrawArraysIndirect was an exact replica of my working piece of code?
